# can boost gregorian date and boost posix time properly calculate unixtime?

Tags: c++, date, boost, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I am trying to write a simple timestamping system that provides epoch seconds and fractional seconds from the current time.  I am using boost library and have something like this:

```
const boost::posix_time::ptime epoch(boost::gregorian::date(1970, 1, 1));
boost::posix_time::ptime time() {
    boost::posix_time::ptime now = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time();
    return now;
}
boost::posix_time::time_duration dur = (time() - epoch);
```

and then use the following elements to extract the epoch values:

```
dur.total_seconds();
dur.fractional_seconds();
```

Specifically, will this return a proper unix time?  If not, any suggestions as to how to correct it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that should work, but, to be certain, there's always experimental evidence:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
namespace bpt = boost::posix_time;
namespace bg = boost::gregorian;
int main()
{
    bpt::time_duration dur = bpt::microsec_clock::universal_time()
                           - bpt::ptime(bg::date(1970, 1, 1));
    timespec ts;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
    std::cout << std::setfill('0')
              << " boost: " << dur.total_seconds() << '.' << std::setw(6)
                            << dur.fractional_seconds() << '\n'
              << " ctime: " << time(NULL) << '\n'
              << " posix: " << ts.tv_sec << '.' << std::setw(9)
                            << ts.tv_nsec << '\n';
}
```

I get

Linux/gcc

```
 boost: 1361502964.664746
 ctime: 1361502964
 posix: 1361502964.664818326
```

Sun/Sun Studio

```
 boost: 1361503762.775609
 ctime: 1361503762
 posix: 1361503762.775661600
```

AIX/XLC

```
 boost: 1361503891.342930
 ctime: 1361503891
 posix: 1361503891.342946000
```

and even Windows/Visual Studio

```
 boost: 1361504377.084231
 ctime: 1361504377
```

Looks like they all agree on how many seconds passed since `date(1970,1,1)`

Comment: great point on running experimentation, and thanks for the results on the different systems, that helps a lot.  I should have mentioned I was building on Linux/gcc AND windows/vs2010.